# Prove or disprove that the continuity of the partial derivative $\partial_x f$ implies the continuity of $\partial_y f$.

Tags: real-analysis

Can we say that: 'For a function $f:A \to \mathbb R$, $A \subseteq \Bbb R^2$, the continuity of the partial derivative $\partial_x f$ will imply the continuity of $\partial_y f$ at a point $(a,b)\in A,$ provided the existence.' Or any counter examples?

Comment: What does "a certain" point mean? as opposed to simply "a point".

Comment: @coffeemath I corrected, thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any differentiable function $g\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ with noncontinuous derivative. Put $f(x,y)=g(y)$. Then $\partial_xf(x,y)=0$, so the partial derivative is continuous. On the other hand, $\partial_yf(x,y)=g'(y)$, so it isn't continuous.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true. Just pick a function that is constant in $x$ and is not continuously differentiable in $y$, e.g. $f(x,y) = y^2\sin(y^{-1})$. Then $\partial_x f = 0$ everywhere, but $\partial_y f$ is not continuous at any point on $y = 0$.

Comment:  Right, the same as my answer.